# Object-Oriented Breadth-First Search Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, object-oriented, comparative-review, breadth-first-search

My goal is to write a GUI application where a user can create a maze and select an algorithm. The passage of the algorithm from a selected start and end point should be visualized.

The following shows only the Breadth-First Search algorithm. During programming, I paid attention to the following things:

- readable APIs
- SOLID-Principles
- short and readable methods

I am very grateful for a code review that focuses on the above points and things I don't yet have in mind.

## Breadth-First Search Algorithm

### An Example

> ```
> // .. build graph ..
>
> BreadthFirstSearch breadthFirstSearch = BreadthFirstSearch.of(graph);
> TraversalTable traversalTable = breadthFirstSearch.searchFrom(a);
> Path path = traversalTable.to(b);
> ```

### Breadth-First Search

```java
public class BreadthFirstSearch {
    private Graph graph;

    private BreadthFirstSearch(Graph graph) {
        this.graph = graph;
    }

    public static BreadthFirstSearch of(Graph graph) {
        return new BreadthFirstSearch(graph);
    }

    public TraversalTable searchFrom(Vertex startVertex) {
        Queue<Vertex> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        TraversalTable traversalTable = new TraversalTable();

        queue.add(startVertex);
        traversalTable.add(new Traversal.Builder().withSuccessor(startVertex)
                                                  .withPredecessor(new NonVertex())
                                                  .withDistance(new Distance(0))
                                                  .build());

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex currentVertex = queue.poll();

            for (Vertex neighbor : graph.neighborsOf(currentVertex)) {
                if (traversalTable.containsNot(neighbor)) {
                    Distance distance = traversalTable.distanceOf(currentVertex);
                    Traversal traversal = new Traversal.Builder().withSuccessor(neighbor)
                                                                 .withPredecessor(currentVertex)
                                                                 .withDistance(distance.increment())
                                                                 .build();
                    traversalTable.add(traversal);
                    queue.add(neighbor);
                }
            }
        }

        return traversalTable;
    }
}
```

### TraversalTable

```java
public class TraversalTable {

    private static Traversal.Builder DEFAULT_TRAVERSAL_BUILDER = new Traversal.Builder().withPredecessor(new NonVertex())
                                                                                        .withDistance(Distance.INFINITE);

    private final Map<Vertex, Traversal> vertexByPredecessor;

    TraversalTable(Map<Vertex, Traversal> vertexByPredecessor) {
        this.vertexByPredecessor = vertexByPredecessor;
    }

    TraversalTable() {
        this.vertexByPredecessor = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void add(Traversal traversal) {
        vertexByPredecessor.put(traversal.getSuccessor(), traversal);
    }

    public Distance distanceOf(Vertex vertex) {
        return traversalOf(vertex).getDistance();
    }

    public Vertex predecessorOf(Vertex vertex) {
        return traversalOf(vertex).getPredecessor();
    }

    public Path to(Vertex vertex) {
        return isNotAccessible(vertex)
                ? Path.empty()
                : to(predecessorOf(vertex), Path.startWith(vertex));
    }

    private Path to(Vertex vertex, Path path) {
        return vertex.isPresent()
                ? to(predecessorOf(vertex), path.append(vertex))
                : path;
    }

    public boolean isAccessible(Vertex vertex) {
        return distanceOf(vertex).isNotInfinite();
    }

    public boolean isNotAccessible(Vertex vertex) {
        return !isAccessible(vertex);
    }

    public boolean containsNot(Vertex vertex) {
        return !contains(vertex);
    }

    public boolean contains(Vertex vertex) {
        return vertexByPredecessor.containsKey(vertex);
    }

    private Traversal traversalOf(Vertex vertex) {
        return vertexByPredecessor
                .getOrDefault(vertex, DEFAULT_TRAVERSAL_BUILDER.withSuccessor(vertex).build());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) { /* ... */ }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { /* ... */ }

    @Override
    public String toString() { /* ... */ }

}
```

## Looking for Recommendation

### Recursion

In `TraversalTable` the method `to` calls a overloaded private method `to` which builds recursively the `Path`.
In my opinion it looks cleaner that the previous while loop

> ```java
> public Path to(Vertex vertex) {
>     if (isAccessible(vertex))
>         return Path.empty();
>
>     Path path = Path.startWith(vertex);
>
>     Vertex predecessor = predecessorOf(vertex);
>     while (predecessor.isPresent()) {
>         path.append(predecessor);
>         predecessor = predecessorOf(predecessor);
>     }
>
>     return path; 
> }
> ```

However, this method has the advantage of containing all the logic within a method, rather than my current solution where I shared the logic. Do you have a suggestion of legibility and maintainability?

### Level Of Indentation

The method `searchFrom` in `BreadthFirstSearch` has a to high level of Indentation, but I left it that way because the algorithm is so well known.

> ```java
> public TraversalTable searchFrom(Vertex startVertex) {
>     // 1 lvl
>     while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
>         // 2 lvl
>         for (Vertex neighbor : graph.neighborsOf(currentVertex)) {
>             // 3 lvl
>             if (traversalTable.containsNot(neighbor)) {
>                 // 4 lvl
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     return traversalTable 
> }
> ```

If I split the logic into my own methods, I can reduce the level of indentation, but because of the variables that share the lower methods with the root method, they must be delegated, which makes the method's signatures unclear to me..

```java
public TraversalTable searchFrom(Vertex startVertex) {
    Queue<Vertex> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    TraversalTable traversalTable = new TraversalTable();

    queue.add(startVertex);
    traversalTable.add(new Traversal.Builder().withSuccessor(startVertex)
                                              .withPredecessor(new NonVertex())
                                              .withDistance(new Distance(0))
                                              .build());
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Vertex currentVertex = queue.poll();
        traversalAllNeighbors(currentVertex, traversalTable, queue);
    }
}

private void traversal(Vertex successor, Vertex predecessor, TraversalTable traversalTable) {
    Distance distance = traversalTable.distanceOf(currentVertex);
    Traversal traversal = new Traversal.Builder().withSuccessor(neighbor)
                                                 .withPredecessor(currentVertex)
                                                 .withDistance(distance.increment())
                                                 .build();
    traversalTable.add(traversal);
}

private void traversalAllNeighbors(Vertext vertex, TraversalTable traversalTable, Queue<Vertex> queue) {
    for (Vertex neighbor : graph.neighborsOf(vertex)) {
        if (traversalTable.containsNot(neighbor)) {
          traversal(neighbor, vertex, traversalTable);
          queue.add(neighbor);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Additional to these two classes I implemented a `Path` and `Traversal` but this does not add any logic to the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

```
new Traversal.Builder()
    .withSuccessor(...)
    .withPredecessor(currentVertex)
    .withDistance(distance.increment())
    .build();
```

Having to manually create the Builder instance with new goes against readability as it clutters the caller's code with knowledge of the Builder class. Explicit new operation binds the code to a certain class. I prefer

```
Traversal.withSuccessor(...)
    .withPredecessor(currentVertex)
    .withDistance(distance.increment())
    .build();
```

...where withSuccessor implicitely creates the Builder instance that corresponds to the meaning of withSuccessor(...). It allows a more readable way for instantiating objects when you have more than one way of instantiation. The Builder is still a public and visible to the caller, but they don't have to import it.

Comment: that was the only thinking i came up with... provide a builder for the initial traversal... `new Traversal.InitalBuilder().withSuccessor(startVertex))
                                              .build();`

Comment: @MartinFrank, @TorbenPutkonen. What do you think if the `Traversal` class is `private` and you would build up a `Traversal` trough the `TraversalTable` like:
`traversalTable.addTraversal().withSuccessor(...).withPredecessor(...).withDistance(...).build()`? 

Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Roman the builder pattern is *in general* a good option, but it is a bit clumsy for the *initial traversal* since the first traversal does not have a distance nor a predecessor...

Comment: @MartinFrank For that I wrote a class `NonVertex` which represents `null` (I know.. I need a better name :P) and the distance would be 0: `...Builder().withSuccessor(...).withPredecessor(new NonVertex()).withDistance(new Distance(0)).build()`

Comment: @Roman since you already know these parameters are null when you create an *initial* traversal you could as well skip them... it's already know the initial traversal does not have a predecessor nor a distance. so use a initialBuilder instead of the default builder

Comment: @MartinFrank ahhh you mean that this are irrelevant information! I see.. maybe something like `..Builder().onlyWithSuccessor(...);` Yes, I think this could look nice :P

Comment: @Roman sorry my english really in need of improvement =) thank you for re-writing my point in such an proper way! and thanks for appreciating it